# Libreria allegro y Mingw en W10

Tags: c++, compilar, allegro

me estoy iniciando en la programación con C++ y he encontrado unos tutoriales muy interesantes para recrear juegos arcade retro. En estos tutoriales se usa la libreria allegro 4 y mingw.

Bien, estoy en W10 y tengo esto:

Allegro 4.2.3 (usada en los tutoriales)

Mingw-w64 x86_64-posix-seh-rev0 8.1

Mingw está en incluido en el PATH y funcionando, he copiado también el contenido de cada carpeta de Allegro en la carpeta correspondiente de MinGw, pero cuando intento compilar un hola mundo de prueba con #include <allegro.h> el compilador me devuelve el error -No such file or directory-

He probado con la version i686 de MinGw, con versiones anteriores, he descargado diferentes versiones de la libreria, una de ellas construida con la misma versión de MinGw que yo estaba usando, le he indicado manualmente donde buscar los include pero nada parece funcionar.

Creo que descargaré CodeBlocks, parece más sencillo armarlo todo ahí, pero no me quiero quedar con la duda de saber por qué no funciona.

**EDIT**

Lo último que intenté:

MinGW-w64 x86_64 osix-seh-rev0 8.1
Allegro 4.4.2

g++ -I"C:\MinGW\mingw64\include" -L"C:\MinGW\mingw64\lib" -lallegro-4.4.2-mt -o test.exe test.cpp

esto me devuelve errores de Skipping Incompatible, ¿será porque la libreria es 32bits y el compilador 64? Intenté añadiendo -m32 pero no funcionó.

Comment: A que te refieres con: *he copiado también el contenido de cada carpeta de Allegro en la carpeta correspondiente de MinGw*? Que fue lo que hiciste exactamente?

Comment: Dentro de la carpeta de Allegro hay 3 carpetas, bin, include y lib, según el tutorial de instalación, hay que copiar el contenido de cada una en la correspondiente de MinGw. @Pablochaches

Comment: Que tutorial estas usando?

Comment: Para instalar la librería, el de la propia wiki de Allegro

Comment: Extract the relevant directories into your MinGW install's include & library paths:

Find out where you installed MinGW (C:\msys64 is the default).

The .zip contains three directories under allegro\: bin\ include\ lib\.

Extract the files from each to e.g. C:\msys64\mingw64\bin, C:\msys64\mingw64\include, C:\msys64\mingw64\lib respectively. @Pablochaches

Comment: Ahh, entonces voy a verlo en su wiki. Ahorita en un rato lo veo